# I want to clear old output using python and output should be new updating with the new time in the same place

Tags: python-3.7

I want to build up my own clock format. But the problem is that I could not update the same output in same place. so, I want to clear the screen for the old output and update the new one in the same place.

```
import time
year=2019
days=198
hour=9
minute=51
sec=0
s='PM'
while(sec==0):
    for i in range(1,60):
        time.sleep(1)
        sec=i
        print("{}:{}:{} ".format(hour,minute,sec) + s)
        if(sec==59):
            print('\n')
            minute=minute+1
            sec=0
            print("{}:{}".format(hour,minute), end='\n')
            if(minute==59):
                print('\n')
                hour=hour+1
                print("hour=%d"%hour,end='\n')
                minute=0
                if(hour==12):
                    print('\n')
                    if(s=="PM"):
                        s="AM"
                    else:
                        s="PM"
                    days=days+1
                    hour=0
                    print("days=%d"%days,end="\n")
                    if(days==365):
                        year=year+1
                        print(year)
                        days=0
                    else:
                        pass
```

output should be  update in single place.
6/22/2019  11:47 am
not like
6/22/2019  11:48 am
6/22/2019  11:49 am
6/22/2019  11:50 am

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the screen displaying nothing other than the clock, call `os.system('cls')`. And if you're on Linux, put `clear` where `cls` is.